# Print Data Fetched From An API To A Console Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, sqlite, sqflite

I have fetched data from an api, but instead of printing it in a UI, I want to use the data for something else(specifically store the data in a sqlite database). My challenge is how do i get the individual items(posts) and call the createItem function from the SQLHelper class to save each of the items in the sqlite database.

Here is my code

```
  Future<List<Post>> fetchPost() async {
    final response =
    await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>();
      
      
      // Loop through parsed. This  is where i am having issues
      // create an entry into the database here
      sqlHelper!.createItem("id", "title");
      
      
      
      return parsed.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromMap(json)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
```

How do i use forEach to loop through the data? If you can add some error handling, that will be great.

But if have any idea how i can make a bulk entry into the sqlite database is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting `json.decode(response.body)` as a single `Map` rather than as a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

Change:

```dart
final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>();
```

To:

```dart
final parsed = json.decode(response.body) as List;
final posts = parsed.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>().map(Post.fromMap) ;

for (final post in posts) {
  sqlHelper!.createItem(post.id, post.title);
}

return posts;
```